# how to calculate element created by append?

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate summary of price*quantity how to do that?

Table 1 :click add for create detail in table2

```
<table width="60%" border="1">
          <tr>
                <td align="center">menu</td>
            <td align="center">quantity</td>
            <td align="center">price</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr id="workplace-view-menu">
          <td id="workplace-menu">coffee</td>
    <td id="workplace-number">5</td>
    <td id="workplace-price">50</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="button" value="add" id="workplace-submit" name="workplace-submit" class="btn-green">
</td>
</tr>
          <tr id="workplace-view-menu">
          <td id="workplace-menu">food</td>
    <td id="workplace-number">2</td>
    <td id="workplace-price">70</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="button" value="add" id="workplace-submit" name="workplace-submit" class="btn-green">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table 2 : created element by jquery and calculate value in td class='ordernumber' * td class='order-price'

```
<table width="200" border="1" id="order-detial">
            <tr>
              <td>menu</td>
              <td>quantity</td>
              <td>price</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
<div id="calculator"></div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#workplace-submit').click(function(){
        var menu=$('#workplace-menu-name').val();
        var number=$('#workplace-number').val();
        var price=$('td#workplace-price').text();
        $('#order-detial').append('<tr class="order-detials"><td>'+menu+'</td><td class="order-number">'+number+'</td><td class="order-price">'+price+'</td><td><button class="btn-green"  onclick="OrderRemove(this)">delete</button></td></tr>');

    OrderRemove = function(el) {
        $(el).parents("tr").remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be reassigning ids to those table cells, or your buttons. You should use classes instead, and your jQuery should be looking for the cells like this: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.workplace-number').text()`

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Comment: where should the calculated value kept?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3H4dH/2/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny it ok,but when delete value it not' now summary value

Comment: @user2773795 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3H4dH/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have duplicate id values, use class attribute like

```
<table width="60%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">menu</td>
        <td align="center">quantity</td>
        <td align="center">price</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="workplace-view-menu">
        <td class="workplace-menu">coffee</td>
        <td class="workplace-number">5</td>
        <td class="workplace-price">50</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" value="add" class="workplace-submit" name="workplace-submit" class="btn-green" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="workplace-view-menu">
        <td class="workplace-menu">food</td>
        <td class="workplace-number">2</td>
        <td class="workplace-price">70</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" value="add" class="workplace-submit" name="workplace-submit" class="btn-green" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="200" border="1" id="order-detial">
    <tr>
        <td>menu</td>
        <td>quantity</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="calculator"></div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $orderDetial = $('#order-detial');

    $('.workplace-submit').click(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var menu = $.trim($tr.find('.workplace-menu').text());
        var number = $.trim($tr.find('.workplace-number').text());
        var price = $.trim($tr.find('.workplace-price').text());
        $('<tr class="order-detials"><td>' + menu + '</td><td class="order-number">' + number + '</td><td class="order-price">' + price + '</td><td><button class="btn-green btn-delete">delete</button></td></tr>').appendTo($orderDetial).data('total', (parseInt(number) * parseFloat(price)) || 0);

        recalc();

    });

    function recalc() {
        var total = 0;
        $orderDetial.find('tr.order-detials').each(function () {
            total += ($(this).data('total') || 0)
        });

        $('#calculator').text(total)
    }

    $orderDetial.on('click', '.btn-delete', function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        recalc();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3H4dH/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly IDs are unique, you should not use the same ID twice.
Instead use classes.

If you wish to calculate the Total price simply do this

```
var number=$('#workplace-number').val();
var price=$('td#workplace-price').text();
var subtotal = parseInt(number) * parseFloat(price);
```

Although this will always get the values of the **first** #workplace-number and #workplace-price values.

Even if the second button is pressed.

Comment: it not result when your added